# Passing Enum as variable to Relay Qraphql query

Tags: relayjs, relay, graphcool, relaymodern, prisma-graphql

```
subscription userSubscription($filter: UserSubscriptionFilter!) {
  User(filter: $filter) {
      mutation
      node {
          name
          addresses {
              id
              pincode
          }
      }
  }}
```

in this subscription query i need to pass filter variable with value

```
const subscriptionConfig = {
    subscription: updateQPListSubscription,
    variables: {filter:{mutation_in: ["CREATED"]}},
```

However CREATED is an enum, how do i pass it as filter variable

If i hard-code in query itself then its working .... for example below query is working

```
subscription userSubscription {
  User(filter: {mutation_in: [CREATED] node:{name_contains:"ankit"}}) {
      mutation
      node {
          name
          addresses {
              id
              pincode
          }
      }
  }}
```

i want to pass the whole filter variable dynamically using the variables field when setting up the subscription

In graphcool playground also it does not work, however it accept the query variable i passed

Comment: can you please show your graphql definition of UserSubscriptionFilter and enums?